# 8051 : do job for 10 seconds

Tags: c, timer, 8051

I have a problem with 8051 timers.I want to start and run motor for 10 seconds and after that stop completely . Anyway this is my electronic circuit.
[electronic circuit Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RtHR.jpg)
And this is my Code :

```
#include <reg51.h>

sbit motor=P2^0;

void delay(){
    int i;
    motor=1;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        TMOD=0x01;
        TL0=0xFF;
        TH0=0xFF;
        TR0 = 1;
        while(TF0==0);
        TR0 = 0;
        TF0=0;
    }
    motor=0;  
}

void main(void)
{ 
    motor=0;
    delay();   
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @D.Hot The timer doesn't work and the motor stops in the first place.

Comment: You should give a more detailed description of what works and what fails (error messages or wrong behavior) to get more helpful feedback here. If people have to guess, they won´t answer or downvote.

Comment: Do you realise the timer counts *up*? That fits the facts: the motor stops right away.

Comment: I don't get any error when I compile it and when I use simulator. I have a problem with logic of codes.
when I run simulator , the motor stops and doesn't work.so i want the motor to start working for 10 seconds and stop after that. @D.Hot

Comment: Have you tried `TL0=0; TH0=0;` ?

Comment: Ok thanks, I replaced 0xFF with -255 . so now the works but it doesn't stop anyway @WeatherVane

Comment: I change my variebles TL0=0; TH0=0 . so it's work not but it doesn't stop. @WeatherVane

Comment: Be prepared to experiment. Better, read the data sheet or tutorials to figure out how to calculate the time interval.

Comment: 0xFF isn't -255, it is -128 on 2s complement

Comment: Ok, what is my problem ? I can't figure out. how much TL and TH must be ?
please help me to complete the project :((  @AminNegm-Awad

Comment: If `0xFFFF` is too fast and `0x0000` is too slow, next try `0x8888`. If that is too fast go to `0x4444`, if it is too slow go to `0xCCCC` and so on.

Comment: `0xFF` is 255: written to the low counter byte and then to the high counter byte, you were writing `0xFFFF` to the 16-bit counter which means it counts only **1**. `0x00` is 0: written to the low counter byte and then to the high counter byte, you were writing `0x0000` to the 16-bit counter which means it counts **65536**. The timer counter advances upwards.

Comment: @WeatherVane  please edit and fix my codes. I can't fix it on my own.

Comment: The timer value is `TH0*256+TL0`. You know the clock rate on it and can calculate the resulting value. Or you simply try it as @WeatherVane said. However, `0x8000`, not `0x8888` … is the average.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I advised using values for experiment that have all digits the same, to reduce the confusion between the low and high order bytes. It was intended to be a binary chop method to converge quickly to a sensible value: if the time is too slow, use the average of the current and previous higher value; if too fast, use the average of the current value and the previous lower value. Perhaps `0x8080` would have been better, followed by `0xC0C0` or `0x4040` etc.

Comment: @xebim 'please edit and fix my codes. I can't fix it on my own' you understand that you have the compiler, linker, debugger, documentation, environment, hardware motor etc. in front of you?  Please explain how we can do anything that you cannot do much more easily.  It's easy for you to try different values, impossible for us.

Comment: @WeatherVane Nothing wrong with your comment. I just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: I don't the the structure of the 8051's timer any more and I'm too lazy by far to look to the data sheet. But if he wants to have a 10 sec interval with a 16 bit timer, the clock rate has to be lower than 7 kHz. I do not believe, that this is possible. It is possible to chain the timers? Otherwise you need a piece of software, too.